# How to add an invoice to protocol proposal

Tags: protocol

Can someone point me in the right direction here.

I am guessing the invoice is somewhere in the Tezos git.

Where is it and how should it be updated for a new proposal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The process to add an invoice to a proposal is described [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_010_PtGRANAD/lib_protocol/init_storage.ml#L27).

You can also look into the [Florence protocol](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_009_PsFLoren/lib_protocol/init_storage.ml#L83) for a real example.

Comment: Thanks for that !